# How is my "if" statement considered a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdnkT.png)

I began a Python course about 3 weeks ago. Although struggling, I would like to know what I am doing wrong in line 3.

Comment: Paste your code here. No need to use an image.

Comment: Missing a colon at the end of your if statement.

Comment: It needs a colon after the if line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `:` to indent the `if` statement -

```
if "LOL" in user_tweet:
```